# Add item to Finder toolbar with terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, customization

You can <kbd>cmd</kbd>-drag an item to the Finder toolbar to have it there permanently, but is there a way you do this in the Terminal?

The closest I've found is this old thread: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=21344

Which suggests something like this:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder FXToolbarItems -array-add '<dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>"/Applications/Chess.app"</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict>'
killall -HUP Finder
```

.. or perhaps ...

```
defaults write com.apple.finder FXToolbarItems -array-add '<dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>"/Applications/Chess.app"</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict><key>item-id</key><string>loc%20</string></dict>'
killall -HUP Finder
```

Neither seem to work. Is there something which works with Yosemite and above?

---

I notice that if I manually add the Chess app to the Finder toolbar, and then output the finder prefs like so:

```
defaults read com.apple.finder >> finderprefs
```

I can see it puts it in like so:

```
"TB Item Plists" =         {
        7 =             {
            "_CFURLAliasData" = <(lots of hex code)>;
            "_CFURLString" = "file:///Applications/Chess.app";
            "_CFURLStringType" = 15;
        };
    };
```

So I guess I need to find a way to do that with `defaults write`

---

More research suggests adding items programmatically is not advisable: http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2015/May/msg00212.html

If you know different, I'd love to know...

Comment: I recommend using the excellent python script [dockutil](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil) for programmatically handling dock items. dockutil --add /Applications/TextEdit.app

Answer (score 4):

This is as far as I’ve got, and it’s not working for me on El Capitan (though, that could be something to do with the beta…).

It seems that `defaults` isn’t comprehensive enough (anymore?) for you to achieve what you want, however you can use PlistBuddy, which on 10.11 is currently found under `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`, to add/remove/edit plist files.

Here are the two commands you’ll can use to add the `_CFURLString` and `_CFURLStringType`:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add "NSToolbar Configuration Browser":"TB Item Plists":8:_CFURLString string "file:///Applications/Chess.app"' ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add "NSToolbar Configuration Browser":"TB Item Plists":8:_CFURLStringType integer 15' ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

The “8” found in both of the commands above is the array index of the item.

No `_CFURLAliasData` is generated (as suggested in several places).  I’ve tried creating an empty `_CFURLAliasData`, but Finder didn’t populate it.

Another issue is that if I add/remove another item using <kbd>cmd</kbd>-drag all the data I’ve added with PlistBuddy gets erased…

Hopefully this information will get someone else partway there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding an entry to `TB Item Plists` you also need to add an entry to `TB Item Identifiers`.

The following code will add Go2Shell to the Finder toolbar:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PLIST=~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
ITEMS=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Default Item Identifiers'" $PLIST | sed '1d; $d'`
APP=/Applications/Go2Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/Go2ShellHelper.app/
POSITION=8

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Identifiers'" $PLIST
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Plists'" $PLIST

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Identifiers' array" $PLIST
i=1
for ITEM in $ITEMS
do
  if [ $i -ne $POSITION ]; then
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Identifiers:$i' string $ITEM" $PLIST
  fi
  ((i++))
done

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Plists:$POSITION:_CFURLString' string 'file://$APP'" $PLIST
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Plists:$POSITION:_CFURLStringType' integer 15" $PLIST
#/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Import 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Plists:$POSITION:_CFURLAliasData' alias_data" $PLIST
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Identifiers:$POSITION' string 'com.apple.finder.loc '" $PLIST

killall -HUP Finder
```

1. The default toolbar items are read
2. Existing identifiers and plists are removed
3. New identifiers are added leaving a space for Go2Shell
4. New plist and identifier are added for Go2Shell (the space after `com.apple.finder.loc` is required)

The `_CFURLAliasData` import is commented out as it's not required for the Finder toolbar, and probably a [bad idea](https://narkive.com/kKXGvKdL:3.623.120) too. If the alias data is required (it may be for the [Finder sidebar or Dock](http://www.magnusviri.com/Mac/cfaliasdata-vs-bookmarkdata.html)), the following code will generate an `alias_data` file for Go2Shell and add it to the plist:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

APP=/Applications/Go2Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/Go2ShellHelper.app/
POSITION=8

python2 -c "from Carbon import File; print File.FSNewAlias(None, File.FSRef('$APP')).data" > alias_data
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Import 'NSToolbar Configuration Browser:TB Item Plists:$POSITION:_CFURLAlias_Data' alias_data" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
rm alias_data
```